# PHPStorm 9 inspection of class inheritance works unexpectable

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

I'm facing the following issue in PHPStorm 9:
Say I have an interface `FieldInterface` that has some methods:

```
namespace Acme;

interface FieldInterface {
    public function methodA();
    public function methodB();
}
```

then I have an abstract class that implements base functionality of the interface. That abstract class has the user to implement certain methods, let's say it's `methodB` in our example:

```
namespace Acme;

abstract class AbstractField implements FieldInterface {
    public function methodA() {
        // implement methodA
    }

    public abstract function methodB(); // have the user implement it
}
```

And finally I have some ready-to-use class `StringField`:

```
namespace Acme;

class StringField extends AbstractField {
    public function methodB() {
        // implement methodB
    }
}
```

At this point everything's going well. But if I add new method in the `FieldInterface`, PHPStorm does not say that anything is wrong with `AbstractField` while it's obvious that I should add `public abstract function newMethod();` in there. However, it spots the error in `StringField` class instead.
It could be understood from the point that abstract classes are made for the purpose of extention, but usually you **extend the abstract class** rather than **implement underlying interface**. The whole meaning of making abstract class is to save user's time for implementing the interface. So why PHPStorm forces me to implement interface in *concrete class* rather than forcing me to implement it in *abstract class* that is explicitly implements the interface.
So I wonder if it is a bug in PHPStorm, or maybe it's done on purpose. Either way, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should be, showing an error in the abstract class would be wrong.

In fact,  `public abstract function methodB();` is redundant because the abstract class already "inherits" this abstract method from the interface as it does not implement it.

The only workaround is to make `AbstractField` *not* abstract.